# Why some line labels in ILASM disassembly are omitted?

Tags: c#, il

I have disassembled some code, using telerik JD, and I notice that some labels are omitted, and portion of the code is useless.

IL:

```
    .method assembly hidebysig instance void xxx (
        int32 p_intPer
    ) cil managed noinlining 
{
    IL_0000: br.s IL_000a

    IL_0002: call

    IL_0007: ldnull
    IL_0008: ldind.ref
    IL_0009: pop

    IL_000a: ldc.i4.0
    IL_000b: brtrue.s IL_0007
    .try
    {
        IL_000d: ldarg.0
        IL_000e: ldfld class [Reader]aaa bbb::getP 
        IL_0013: brfalse IL_0024

        IL_0018: ldarg.0
        IL_0019: ldfld class [Reader]aaa bbb::getP 
        IL_001e: ldarg.1
        IL_001f: callvirt instance void [Reader]aaa::Invoke(int32)

        IL_0024: leave IL_002f
    }
    catch [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        IL_0029: pop
        IL_002a: leave IL_002f
    }

    IL_002f: ret
}
```

C#:

```
        internal void xxx(int per)
    {
        while (0 != 0) { }
        try
        {
            if (this.getP != null)
            {
                this.getP(per);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

I mean `IL_0000 -> IL_0002 -> IL_0007`

Is the decompiler stupid, or is it normal? 
Also, I'm not very skilled in IL, but this doesn't look like the actual source C# to me

Comment: I strongly suspect the IL here has been obfuscated. The lack of any reference to `getP` is pretty damning..

Comment: I've renamed the methods for the example, sorry about that...

Comment: It is seems pretty obvious that the owner of this software does not want you to do this.  So don't do it.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I assume that might also be related to him manually 'obfuscating' the code before posting it.

Comment: @MarkJansen: Apparently so - all of which makes it rather harder to tell what's going on.

Comment: There are quite a few reasons to reverse software apart from cracking or anything malicious

Comment: no problem with that il code , it does exactly the same thing as the c# code  infact it makes the while(0!=0) into a while(true) wich is quite nice :)  ,  the use of null is to align code so that it is not on uneven memory adress and is very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number in the labels are the offset in the methodbody of the following instruction. But not every instruction and operand are of the same size.

- IL_0000: br.s   1byte opcode 1byte operand
- IL_0002: call   1byte opcode 4byte operand
- IL_0007: ldnull  1byte opcode
- IL_0008: ldind.ref 1byte opcode
- [...]

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that the labels skip a few numbers now and then, not every instruction has the same size.